Where to find Austrian statutes from 1778 and 1787 related to obligatory road services?
In a newspaper from mid-XIX c. (printed in Lemberg/Lviv) I've found an article describing the road network of Galicia under Austrian rule. It said that Austria issued (at least) two acts related to obligatory road services for Austrian subjects:

In 1778 the first statute regarding roads was announced - it obliged peasants living up to 2 miles from a main state's road (Polish: gościniec) to serve scharwerk obligations for the state (scharwerk were just obligatory services construction and maintenance of roads, canals etc.).
In 1787 (in times of emperor Joseph II) a regulation was issued which obliged all subjects living up to 3 miles from the road to serve scharwerk obligations.

I couldn't find those documents in the Internet. Could someone point me to where to look for them?

The Austrian National Archive has a project to digitalize old Austrian law from back to the 18th century. https://alex.onb.ac.at/ Maybe you can find something there. But be aware: law wasn't as systematically published as we know it today till ca. 1800.
